# Is it possible to load aliases of a required package from within my package's service provider?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Let's say I am developing a L5 package, and said package uses (and requires on its own `composer.json`) another package which provides some aliases.

Is there a way to load the aliases from within the `register()` function of my service provider?

An example would be a package that uses `laravelcollective/html` and, on its service provider has, on the `register()` function, something like this:

```
    public function register()
    {
        // Whatever else...
        $this->app->register('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');

        // And then I'm looking for something like the following
        // $this->app->alias('HTML', 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade');
        // $this->app->alias('Form', 'Collective\Html\FormFacade');
    }
```

This way the user doesn't have to add the aliases to its app config file and they can actually be used for my own tests with something like testbench.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so answering my own question for posterity, you can get an instance of the `AliasLoader` and load your own aliases. Following the example stated on my question it'd be something like:

```
public function register()
{
    // Whatever else...
    $this->app->register('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');

    // Load HTML and Form aliases
    $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();

    $loader->alias('HTML', 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade');
    $loader->alias('Form', 'Collective\Html\FormFacade');
}
```

That will load the facades on the package, so they can be used.